# How to position tags in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I want to put a tag in the top left-hand corner of the page but I am unsure of how to do it. I have looked on the internet but found nothing so I came here. Thank in advance.

Comment: Top left of what? The parent container? The main window?

Comment: There are several options depending on what you want to achieve. There is position CSS property as well as margin, padding and few other options. Please ask detailed question including some sample

Answer (score 2):

HTML (Hyper Text Markup Language) is used to structure webpages, while CSS would be a site's style or visual appeal and javascript focuses primarily on performing actions. However, as you continue to grow and continue learning Javascript. It can be used to "inject" elements or style toward a page, in hope of making it or things on a website more dynamic. (e.g., dynamically changing a website's color when an event is triggered and /or the value for this new color is set in a variable and/ or changed once the event occurs)

- HTML - think of it like a person: Head, Body, etc.
- CSS - think of it like a person's features: color, animation, ultimately look an feel
- javascript -  like a person performing action: run, jump, shake, etc. or listen for such events

Now, you can use in-line style: `<div style="text-align: center">`
or reference an external style sheet `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/sheet-location/mystyle.css">`

Hope that helps a bit.

Resource

- HTML: https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp
- CSS: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp